# Rust Application crashes when trying to debug with Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, debugging, rust, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a very simple Rust application in VS Code. The application crashes on line 5. It runs fine without the debugger.

```
use std::io;
fn main() {
    println!("Hi");
    let mut lim = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut lim).expect("Error reading line"); //crash
    println!("Upper limit: {}", lim);
}
```

The launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    // Verwendet IntelliSense zum Ermitteln möglicher Attribute.
    // Zeigen Sie auf vorhandene Attribute, um die zugehörigen Beschreibungen anzuzeigen.
    // Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/learn.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "compile"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "compile",
            "command": "cargo", // Could be any other shell command
            "args": [
                "build"
            ],
            "type": "shell"
        }
    ]
}
```

I really don't know what more is there to say. This is really the bare minimum of code one could imagine, I followed the tutorials with setting this up. I updated Rust, all the other dependencies are freshly installed.

The error looks like this:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF9C03CC09B (ntdll.dll) in learn.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.

There's really not a lot I can see that might be a mistake on my side.

Update:
Using the following versions:

> rustup 1.11.0 (e751ff9f8 2018-02-13)
>
> cargo 0.19.0-nightly (fa7584c14 2017-04-26)
>
> rustc 1.19.0-nightly (6a5fc9eec 2017-05-02)
>
> VSCode 1.23.1
>
> Plugins:
>   C/C++ 0.17.1
>   Rust 0.4.2
>   rls 0.4.4

Comment: You are trying to read from standard in — is that supported inside your debugger?

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue on a Windows 10 VM using Rust 1.26 (`x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`).

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't actually know. It may not. Where can I find that out ?  
Edit: Tried with an SDL2 example project, same thing. It's not using stdin.